# Programmatically created UITableViewCell is not correctly displayed after UITableView scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, anchor

This is my first trial of programmatically created tableview cells. So maybe I am overseeing some basics.
I took over and adapted this piece of code to implement a chat functionality using a tableview. It covers a ChatMessageCell for the tableviewcell and a ChatViewController for the tableview. The ChatMessageCell checks every chat message, wether it is Incoming (user is different from the current user) or Outgoing. If it is an Incoming the cell is pinned to the left on a white background and if it is Outgoing to the right on a green background. The cell size are adjusted to the text of the chat message, so that it shows either on the left or on the right of the screen (like in WhatsApp).

Now the issue:
When the tableview is initially built, everything shows up in the right way and the cells is adjusted to the left or to the right. As soon as the user scrolls the tableview, the cells are stretched to take the whole width of the screen, regardless whether they are Incoming or Outgoing. Any hint, what is wrong?

Below is the snippet for the cell creation in the ChatViewController:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
        cell.configure(with: messages[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
```

And the ChatMessageCell class:

[picture shows the last cells after the scroll. the first ones are correctly displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CixD.png)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    let messageBgView = UIView()
    
    
    // change background view colour accordingly
    var isIncoming: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            messageBgView.backgroundColor = isIncoming ? UIColor.white : #colorLiteral(red: 0.8823529412, green: 0.968627451, blue: 0.7921568627, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        addSubview(messageBgView)
        addSubview(messageLabel)
        messageBgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageBgView.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // set constraints for the message and the background view
        let constraints = [
            messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 24),
            messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -24),
            
            messageBgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.topAnchor, constant: -16),
            messageBgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -16),
            messageBgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            messageBgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16)
        ]
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

        selectionStyle = .none
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    // what we will call from our tableview method
    func configure(with model: Chat) {
        isIncoming = (model.senderId != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
        if isIncoming {
            let sender = model.senderNameInApp
            // align to the left
            let nameAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.orange,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
                ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
            // sender name at top, message at the next line
            let senderName = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sender + "\n", attributes: nameAttributes)
            let message = NSMutableAttributedString(string: model.message)
            senderName.append(message)
            messageLabel.attributedText = senderName
            messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
            messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = false
        }
        else {
            // align to the right
            messageLabel.text = model.message
            messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
            messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = false
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but when you modify constraints at runtime it's highly recommended **first** to **deactivate** one constraint and then activate the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach - which you may find easier - is to create both Leading and Trailing constraints - one for ***incoming*** and one for ***outgoing***, but give them different `Priority` values. To change your alignment, you can swap the priorities.

For example, updating your cell class (the numbers correspond to the comments I added) like this:

1. declare constraint variables to use for alignment
2. set the ContentHuggingPriority of the label to keep it from filling the width
3. create the Leading / Trailing constraints
4. if desired, limit the max-width of the message label
5. Activate both incoming and outgoing constraints
6. Update the priorities of the constraints as needed

You *should* be able to just drop this right in to replace your current `ChatMessageCell` class:

```
class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    let messageBgView = UIView()
    
    // (1) constraints for messsage aligmment
    var incomingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var outgoingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // change background view colour accordingly
    var isIncoming: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            messageBgView.backgroundColor = isIncoming ? UIColor.white : #colorLiteral(red: 0.8823529412, green: 0.968627451, blue: 0.7921568627, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        addSubview(messageBgView)
        addSubview(messageLabel)
        messageBgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageBgView.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // (2) "hug" the message content
        messageLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        
        // (3) create Leading / Trailing constraints so we can update their Priority later
        incomingConstraint = messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32.0)
        outgoingConstraint = messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -32.0)

        // set constraints for the message and the background view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 24),
            messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -24),

            // (4) limit message label to 75% of width (if desired)
            messageLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            
            // (5) activate both leading / trailing constraints
            incomingConstraint,
            outgoingConstraint,

            messageBgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.topAnchor, constant: -16),
            messageBgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -16),
            messageBgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            messageBgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            
        ])
        
        selectionStyle = .none
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    // what we will call from our tableview method
    func configure(with model: Chat) {
        isIncoming = (model.senderId != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
        if isIncoming {
            let sender = model.senderNameInApp
            // align to the left
            let nameAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.orange,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
                ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
            // sender name at top, message at the next line
            let senderName = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sender + "\n", attributes: nameAttributes)
            let message = NSMutableAttributedString(string: model.message)
            senderName.append(message)
            messageLabel.attributedText = senderName
            
            // (6) update leading / trailing constraint priorities
            outgoingConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
            incomingConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
            
            // don't do this here
            //messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
            //messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = false
        }
        else {
            // align to the right
            messageLabel.text = model.message

            // (6) update leading / trailing constraint priorities
            incomingConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
            outgoingConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh

            // don't do this here
            //messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
            //messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = false
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: awesome - it worked perfectly! Just the the orange color for the sender name used in incoming messages was appearing in some outgoing messages when scrolling. I fixed that by overriding prepareForReuse and setting the messageLabel.attributedText and messageLabel.text to nil.
Many thanks!